# SharePoint 2010 - Transfer Content Type from Stage to Prod

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010, content-type

I need to transfer a Content Type from the stage env. to the prod.
It is possible? It is possible to use the same id´s for the Content Type?
(Because I want to bind a workflow to this Content Type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vssharepointtoolsblog/archive/2010/03/23/importing-fields-using-the-import-sharepoint-solution-package-project.aspx) could be helpful. Examples for export & import are there.